# UIActivityViewController: Close button in share sheet becomes transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I use `UIActivityViewController` to share an image the close button becomes transparent. I can click on its frame button but it is invisible for the user. And you cannot click outside to close on the sheet.

```
let activityItemMetadata = LinkMetadataManager(qrImage: image)
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(
                   activityItems: [activityItemMetadata],
                   applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
}
            
activityVC.activityItemsConfiguration = [
    UIActivity.ActivityType.mail,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.message
] as? UIActivityItemsConfigurationReading
            
activityVC.isModalInPresentation = false
self.present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJoez.png)]

Close button appear like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of your `UIActivityViewController` code is wrong.

1. You should not be creating a `LinkMetadataManager` from the image and then using it as the item you wish to share.
2. You are trying to create an array of activities and setting those as the activity configuration. This is all wrong.

Your code should look more like the following:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ image ], applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in
    if completed || activityType == nil {
        // activity view is being dismissed
    }
}
present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

If you have a need to exclude certain activities you can add a line like the following:

```
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [ .assignToContact ] // Optionally exclude specific activities
```

If you want a bit more control you make use of `UIActivityItemsConfiguration`. The following is an example:

```
let configuration = UIActivityItemsConfiguration(objects: [ image ])
configuration.perItemMetadataProvider = { (index, key) in
    switch key {
    case .linkPresentationMetadata:
        // Maybe make use of your LinkMetadataManager class here
        var info = LPLinkMetadata()
        info.title = "Some Title"
        return info
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItemsConfiguration: configuration)
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in
    if completed || activityType == nil {
        // activity view is being dismissed
    }
}
present(activityVC, animated: true)
```